# R autoload library when loading data file

Tags: r, package, autoloader, data-files

Is there a possibility to define a library that gets loaded, when one reads in a saved object in an .rdata file. E.g.: after running:

```
library(data.table)
dt1 = data.table(a=1:10,b=letters[1:10])
save(dt1,file="dt.rdata")
```

dt1 is saved dt.rdata.

Alas when reading that file in to a pristine R session (e.g. by double clicking on the file in windows explorer) dt1 is available, but corresponding data.table commands can only be used after issuing an additional

```
library(data.table)
```

in the newly opened R session. Is there some way to define within the data file, that certain packages are to be loaded or some other commands are to be performed before/after reading in the respective file?

Comment: Maybe the easiest is to put that into a function. Something like `myReader <- function(fileName) {; require(data.table); load(fileName);};`. Then read in the data `myReader("dt.rdata")`.

Comment: Double-clicking on a file does not exactly make it part of a reproducible analysis workflow. It's fine for "one-offs", but in my experience "one-offs" quickly become full on scripts and having all of the proper scaffolding in place (`library()` calls, setup defaults, data read section, data cleaning section, EDA, models, charts) saves a great deal of pain in the long run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save your data into a different workspace and add a function called `.First` which load the library.

```
.First <- function(){library(data.frame)}
```